# Company fields do not work in the body of an X.M.L. report

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

When customizing a sale order X.M.L. report in Odoo 8, adding `company` fields inside the *body* does not work. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <template id="my_report_body" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/div[3]" position="replace">
        <p t-if="o.date_order" class="text-right">
          À <span t-field="company.city"/>, le <span t-field="o.date_order"/>
        </p>
      </xpath>
    </template>
  </date>
</openerp>
```

raises the following exception:

```
QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'" while evaluating
```

However it works in the *header* or *footer*. How can I make it work in the body too?

Comment: To work, `company` should be a field.

Comment: If i remember correct, in RML reports `company` was a global variable in context of report rendering. Maybe this was mistakenly leading the questioner to the assumption to use it in QWeb reports, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used not register/declare field *company*.

Instead of *company* use *company_id* field.

Try with following code.

Replace

```
<span t-field="company.city"/>
```

with

```
<span t-field="o.company_id.city"/>
```